# HTML 5 file reader image size not correct on the first load

Tags: jquery, image, file, html, filereader

I have a very strange problem with the HTML 5 file reader. I am loading an image an appending it to a specified . Oddly sometimes the image is not correctly sized or does not show at all, but when I load the same image again, it perfectly works. Firebug tells me that the image is loaded correctly in any case.

Here is how I do it:

```
function getImg(evt, id) {
var files = evt.target.files;
var file = files[0]
var filename = file.name;
previewimg = filename;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    //to empty the div every time a new image is loaded
    $(id).empty();
    readImgData(e, id, filename);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
function readImgData(e, id, filename) {
var img = new Image();
img.name = filename;
var split = filename.split('.');
img.id = split[0]
img.src = e.target.result;
$(id).append(img);
var jimg = $("#" + img.id);
var width = jimg.width();
var height = jimg.height();
console.log('width: ' + width + " height: " + height);
if(id == '#showpreview') {
    jimg.attr({
        'id' : img.id + 'prev'
    });
    console.log(id)
    if(width > 400) {
        var divider = width / 400;
        var newheight = height / divider;
        jimg.css({
            'width' : 400,
            'height' : newheight
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The img element will also fire an "onload" event after you assign the src.
You have to listen to that.

Problem is similar to :
[FileReader+canvas image loading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004011/filereadercanvas-image-loading-problem)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `var width = jimg.width();` will execute before your image is full loaded.

You should add a load event handler to your image to get image dimensions.

Add something like this in your `readImgData` function

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(evt) {
   var width = this.width;
   var height = this.height;
            console.log("Width " + width + ", Height : " + height);
    };
img.src = e.target.result;
```

this should work...